# sqlpackage.exe ignoring BlockOnPossibleDataLoss?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssdt, visual-studio-2012, data-tier-application

I have a dacpac that has set the BlockOnPossibleDataLoss set to false, however the deployment is blocked when I run it with sqlpackage.exe, telling me "The column [a] is being dropped, data loss could occur."

However when I use the exact same deployment profile and publish from Visual Studio 2012 it goes through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the issue, 
I execute sqlpackage.exe within a powershell script where the error handling is set like

```
$Script:ErrorActionPreference = "Inquire"
```

since i never got the Inquire I assumed the problem was with sqlpackage.exe, however I had another powershell script included after the ErrorActionPreference was set, turned out the included script also had the ErrorActionPreference set, but to "Stop". Still I believe if I have set BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false it should not result in an error, but at least I now have a way to handle it.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried executing sqlpackage.exe with `/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false` in the command line?

I just used SQLPackage.exe to create a .dacpac file of my test database, then I pubished it with the `/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false` option, and it overwrote my database.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false don't work.

The final solution was in my case, that it also has to be set in the debug settings of the project file:

[image: Project debug settings]

Hope this helps someone! :)

Comment: and if you "publish" directly, you'll have to set up this option in the "advanced" publish option as well!

Comment: In my case this solved partially the issue. Deployment failed however, because a constraint was depending on the object I want to modify.